# What is the (_:xs) notation in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I see the function

```
last_element :: [a] -> a
last_element (_:xs)= last_element xs
```

I don't understand the underscore colon in "(_:xs)". I read that it seperates the head from the list inputted. Is the underscore colon just removing the first digit, or the "head", of the list in a primitive recursive way?

edit, from my understanding, this function would lack a base case. Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

The underscore allows you to pattern match but implies that you will not actually be using the value. Your pattern matching is not exhaustive, so it won't actually work. You'll need to define the missing patterns to fix it:

```haskell
last_element :: [a] -> a
last_element [] = error "Empty List"
last_element [x] = x
last_element (_:xs)= last_element xs
```

Comment: OP's example is missing a base case though.

Comment: How is this different to using an underscore without the colon? I believe you can do pattern matching of say, (Int, String), by just (_ "hello") can't you?

Comment: The colon is the [cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) operator. `(x:xs)` matches the first item of a list as `x`, and the rest of the list as `xs`. Since your function doesn't use the first item in the list, it ignores it using the underscore.

Comment: @JJchips You must include the `,` when pattern matching on an `(Int, String)` because it's the name of the pair constructor, much like how `:` is the name of one of the two constructors for lists.